# jq: reduce and map combination

Tags: jq

Here my current jq script:

```
def reduce_generateId:
    .[] | (. + {generalPractitionerCode: (.UAB_UP + "-" + .UAB_COD_UAB)});

def reduce_generalPractitioner($practitionerRole):
    (reduce $practitionerRole[] as $g (
        {};
        .[$g.oid1 + "-" + $g.oid2].generalPractitioner += ($g | [.id])
    )) as $dict
    | $dict;

reduce_generateId | reduce_generalPractitioner($generalPractitioner)
```

My jq command is:

```
jq -s -f merge-patient.jq --argfile generalPractitioner reduced_ids.json reduced_pacient.json
```

Where `reduced_pacient.json`:

```json
{ "UAB_UP": "00003", "UAB_COD_UAB": "3212", "INVENTAT": "02"}
{ "UAB_UP": "00006", "UAB_COD_UAB": "5881", "INVENTAT": "102"}
{ "UAB_UP": "00006", "UAB_COD_UAB": "5751", "INVENTAT": "102"}
```

and `reduced_ids.json`:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "3e67b455-8cdb-4bc0-a5e1-f90253870fc9",
    "oid1": "04374",
    "oid2": "INFP3"
  },
  {
    "id": "0f22e5ff-70bc-457f-bdaf-7afe86d478de",
    "oid1": "04376",
    "oid2": "INF07"
  }
]
```

As you can see, `redux_generalPractitioner` returns `$dict` straightforwardly. I'm getting this:

```json
{
  "04374-INFP3": {
    "generalPractitioner": [
      "3e67b455-8cdb-4bc0-a5e1-f90253870fc9"
    ]
  },
  "04376-INF07": {
    "generalPractitioner": [
      "0f22e5ff-70bc-457f-bdaf-7afe86d478de"
    ]
  }
}
{
  "04374-INFP3": {
    "generalPractitioner": [
      "3e67b455-8cdb-4bc0-a5e1-f90253870fc9"
    ]
  },
  "04376-INF07": {
    "generalPractitioner": [
      "0f22e5ff-70bc-457f-bdaf-7afe86d478de"
    ]
  }
}
{
  "04374-INFP3": {
    "generalPractitioner": [
      "3e67b455-8cdb-4bc0-a5e1-f90253870fc9"
    ]
  },
  "04376-INF07": {
    "generalPractitioner": [
      "0f22e5ff-70bc-457f-bdaf-7afe86d478de"
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see, I'm getting `$dict` three times.

I don't quite figure out why it's generating three `$dict` instead of one.

If I only perform `reduce_generalPractitioner($generalPractitioner)`, I'm getting:

```json
{
  "04374-INFP3": {
    "generalPractitioner": [
      "3e67b455-8cdb-4bc0-a5e1-f90253870fc9"
    ]
  },
  "04376-INF07": {
    "generalPractitioner": [
      "0f22e5ff-70bc-457f-bdaf-7afe86d478de"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your program input, `reduced_pacient.json` is a stream of three objects. As you have set the `--slurp` flag, the initial context of your script is an array of three elements.

First, you're calling `reduce_generateId` which by iteration `.[]` decomposes the array into its three items. Thus `reduce_generateId` has three outputs.

Next, these are fed by pipe into your `reduce_generalPractitioner` function which consequently is run three times. Each run produces your `$dict` once, yielding three times in total.

Remember: Although your function `reduce_generalPractitioner` has an input parameter, it also has (just like every filter in jq) a general input context (addressed through piping), which determines the value of `.` and subsequently the number of runs.